# iframe has eaten my JavaScript codes. What's going wrong?

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <iframe id="frame" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("test");
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Here, I have placed the JS codes at the bottom of the page. And the result is it's eaten. If I remove the iframe element, the codes work fine. Evidently, the iframe I place here is an empty one without linking to any source. Hence, no other inline JS codes are brought in. BTW, if I put scripts in the head block, they work fine too.

I really don't know WHY? Could anybody give me some comments?

Comment: Use an HTML validator. It will *tell* you what is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use a validator (such as http://html5.validator.nu/ or [http://validator.w3c.org](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)). The biggest problem you have is that you're not closing the iframe with a `</iframe>` tag. Anything between iframe tags will only show for clients who have iframes disabled.

Final code should look like:

```
<iframe id="frame" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0" style="height: 300px; width: 100%">
    This page requires iframes... blah blah.
</iframe>
```

In the future, **always** validate when you're not 110% sure.